# Add svg file as content to the scss file

Tags: reactjs, svg, sass

I have a SVG file and scss file in my development system. I need to add that svg icon to a text box using a class in scss. Is there any method to add svg file as content to the scss file?

any idea like this?

```
.icon-rc-datepicker_calendar {
  &::before {
   content: '\F073';
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please read this article [Optimizing SVGs in data URIs](https://codepen.io/tigt/post/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris) to learn how to use svg as data URIs in CSS

Comment: There are also some good sass mixins for embedding svgs from files ... even replacing tokens to change colours etc. CSS gzips pretty well ... but consider other items such as accessibility. Would inline SVG work for you better?